# Touch position on rotating Sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

i have a simple ball in SpriteKit which is rotating

Lets say i touch the ball on the far right edge several times while it is rotating. The sprite coordinates are different each time because of the rotation. Can i somehow get a constant value here like it is without the rotation?

Comment: Which coordinates? The touch coordinates or the actual sprite coordinates?

Comment: the sprite coordinates